# Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid when Casting to an Integer in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, exception, dbnull

This is the code that appears to be throwing this error:

```
Dim myDataTable As New DataTable()
Using myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    myDataTable.Load(myReader)
End Using

Dim minPos As Integer = myDataTable.Compute("Min(position)", String.Empty)
Dim maxPos As Integer = myDataTable.Compute("Max(position)", String.Empty)


Dim dblData() As Double = Nothing
For iPosition As Integer = minPos To maxPos
    Dim dvDataSlice = New DataView(myDataTable, String.Format("runid>={0} and runid<={1} and position={2} and value is not null", minRunId, maxRunId, iPosition), "value", DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)
    Dim nobs As Integer = dvDataSlice.Count
```

Apparently, this code use to work in Visual Studio 2010 but since migrating it to Visual studio 2015 it is throwing this exception. I am taking over the code support and am a bit rusty with VB.net

Answer (score 0):

`null` values from the database appear in ADO.Net as instances of `DBNull`. My guess is that your data table is empty, which will cause the `min()` and `max()` queries to return `null`. One way to solve this is to store the result in an `Object` instead, and convert to `Integer` only if the result is not `DBNull` (you can use the `IsDbNull()` function for this).